# Hiding text in a navigation menu

Tags: css, text, menu, icons, hide

I found this tutorial online to add menu icons to a wordpress navbar: http://www.wpexplorer.com/adding-images-wordpress-menu/

Which I followed and seems to work great. However, I need to hide the text labels for my menu so that I have just the icons showing.

I found this which is supposed to hide the text: http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/

Which again, seems to work great, but it leave about a 400px section of white space in the menu.

As you can see here: goo.gl/46yUrt

My code:

```
.twitter-icon a{
   padding-left: 30px !important;
   background-image: url(images/icons/Twitter-01.png);
   background-position: left;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   text-indent: 100%;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.twitter-icon a:hover{
   padding-left: 30px !important;
   background-image: url(images/icons/Twitter-02.png);
   background-position: left;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   text-indent: 100%;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Please let me know if you need anymore details (FYI I'll be AFK for a couple hours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something really bad in behavior of your social nav, but if you want to have image icons in all 4 socials, you could try setting:

```
padding: 17px 10px;
font-size: 0px;
```

on your `.nav-social li a` class.

Also, you need to veryfy element with classes `screen-reader-text skip-link` which overflows over social navs so they mouse over effect fails.

Comment: Font-size: 0px seems to hide the text nicely, but could you explain what you mean by "Bad Behavior"? and the 'screen-reader-text' 'skip-link'

Much appreciated :)

Comment: Seems changing 'position: absolute !important;" to 'position: relative;' and adding 'top: -1000px;' seems to hide the "skip to content" options and correcting the mouse over on the icons.

Is there a better way I should be handling this?

Comment: I don't really know what you want to achieve by element: 
`<a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content" title="Skip to content">Skip to content</a>`. I just wanted to point you that this element with the style it had earlier, could overflow over your social buttons and affect their roll over area. Now it looks like it doesn't affect them so it's ok, good luck with further work.

Comment: Yea, I spent some time working on it after you pointed it out, and it seems to have all been sorted out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: simple and brilliant hack .. thanks :) , I wonder how is rendering on old IE versions